# Generic Interface with composed interfaces and multiple concrete implementations

Tags: c#, generics, interface, composition

I want to use a generic interface, that can take other interfaces as properties, that use a concrete implementation. How do I create the pattern, if possible, and how do I resolve the implementation in the service collection. This is going to be used alongside a unit of work and the repository pattern.

I've been trying different techniques and implementations through code. Some have been able to compile, but at runtime they have not been able to get resolved. Part of the question is - can the approach be done, the other have I not resolved this correctly.

```
public class GenericInterface<T, U> : IGenericInterface<T, U>
{
    public T InterfaceOne { get; set; }     // IInterfaceOne
    public U InterfaceTwo { get; set; }     // IInterfaceTwo
}

public interface IInterfaceOne
{
    void DoOne();
    void DoTwo();
}

public interface IInterfaceTwo
{
    void DoThree();
    void DoFour();
}

public class ConcreteImplementation : IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo
{
    public void DoOne()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoTwo()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoThree()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoFour()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Resolver { 

    public void Resolve() {

        // Should be able to use the interfaces and reference the ConcreteImplementation....!?
        // How to resolve in a service collection?
        var genericComposedInterfaces = new GenericInterface<IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo>();
    }
}
```

The desired result is that it should first serve the purpose and secondly get resolved within the service collection / when it is called.

**Update**

Thanks for the help. So I think I was caught between two minds of what I was trying to achieve. All I really wanted was one backing class that was exposed via two interfaces that could be combined into one generic interface. I think the following works.

Generic Interface takes two or several interfaces.

```
public interface ITestGenericInterface<T, U>
{
    T InterfaceOne { get; }
    U InterfaceTwo { get; }
}

public class TestGenericInterface<T, U> : ITestGenericInterface<T, U>
{
    public TestGenericInterface(T interfaceOne, U interfaceTwo)
    {
        InterfaceOne = interfaceOne;
        InterfaceTwo = interfaceTwo;
    }

    public T InterfaceOne { get; }
    public U InterfaceTwo { get; }
}
```

The interfaces with a class that might be used with the above interface.

```
public interface IInterfaceOne
{
    void DoOne();
    void DoTwo();
}

public interface IInterfaceTwo
{
    void DoThree();
    void DoFour();
}

public class ConcreteClass : IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo
{
    public void DoOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoOne()");
    }
    public void DoTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoTwo()");
    }

    public void DoThree()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoDoThreeOne()");
    }

    public void DoFour()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoFour()");
    }
}
```

Registering in the service collection. I don't think I was registering the interface / implementation correctly before which could have been an issue.

```
  services.AddScoped<IInterfaceOne, ConcreteClass>();
  services.AddScoped<IInterfaceTwo, ConcreteClass>();
  services.AddScoped(typeof(ITestGenericInterface<,>), typeof(TestGenericInterface<,>));
```

Trying it out

```
public interface ITestRunner
{
    void Start();
}

public class TestRunner : ITestRunner
{
    private readonly ITestGenericInterface<IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo> _genericTest;

    public TestRunner(
        ITestGenericInterface<IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo> genericTest
        )
    {
        _genericTest = genericTest;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Interface One 
        _genericTest.InterfaceOne.DoOne();
        _genericTest.InterfaceOne.DoTwo();

        // Interface Two
        _genericTest.InterfaceTwo.DoThree();
        _genericTest.InterfaceTwo.DoFour();
    }
}
```

I appreciate that this was probably simpler than it sounded in my initial question. As Flavio Francisco put me on the right track with his first answer, I will up vote it and mark as the answer. Hopefully this will help someone else. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand what you are trying to accomplish with such a twisted design. Please provide us more information about what your problem is.

Comment: You have said that your generic interface *has* two objects, whereas interfaces are usually used to say that a type *is* something or *implements* something. Can you clarify what you want your code to do? In order for a type to implement your generic interface, you need to provide an implementation for it. If the concrete type actually implements the two interfaces, it might be that you can implement both as `return this;`, but you still have to implement the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
public interface IGeneric<T, U>
{
    T InterfaceOne { get; }

    U InterfaceTwo { get; }
}

public class GenericClass : IGeneric<IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo>
{
    private readonly IInterfaceOne interfaceOne;
    private readonly IInterfaceTwo interfaceTwo;

    public GenericClass(IInterfaceOne interfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo interfaceTwo)
    {
        this.interfaceOne = interfaceOne;
        this.interfaceTwo = interfaceTwo;
    }

    public IInterfaceOne InterfaceOne { get { return this.interfaceOne; } }
    public IInterfaceTwo InterfaceTwo { get { return this.interfaceTwo; } }
}

public class ClassOne : IInterfaceOne
{
    public void DoOne()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoTwo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ClassTwo : IInterfaceTwo
{
    public void DoFour()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoThree()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Resolver:

```
       IGeneric<IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo> genericClass = new GenericClass(new ClassOne(), new ClassTwo());

       genericClass.InterfaceOne.DoOne();
```

Hope that what you want is it.

Comment: Hi Flavio, thank you for your help, this does cover the main implementation of the issue I am facing, however, the ideal goal is to have one class that can be used by two interfaces. For example, my motive for this is to have one interface as a type of QueryProcessor and the other one as a CommandHandler type of interface. Maybe this is going too far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instance of a class that implements two interfaces you could do it also:

```
public interface IInterfaceOneAndTwo : IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo
{

}

public interface IInterfaceOne
{
    void DoOne();
    void DoTwo();
}

public interface IInterfaceTwo
{
    void DoThree();
    void DoFour();
}
```

Your concrete class:

```
public class ConcreteClass : IInterfaceOneAndTwo
{
    public void DoFour()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoOne()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoThree()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoTwo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and your resolver:

```
IInterfaceOneAndTwo concreteClass = new ConcreteClass();

concreteClass.DoOne();
```